# How to use loop function in google sheets to past data from one sheet to other?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

I have 2 sheets in my workbook sheet 1 a simple invoice and sheet 2 data sheet I update sheet2 on daily basis and record transactions for various clients In sheet1 I want to make a monthly invoice for each client based on all their transactions recorded in sheet 2 I need a script that can look up the value of "Cell 5" of sheet-1 in column-B of sheet-2 and copy all the corresponding transaction to sheet-1 column B~D I hope this make sense Thanks in advance
here is the sheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jDzmyKsLD1zzfmJ4yNrNEuzb-lCmQSBIq_ba55r-T3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

check this code
I hope this helps you
although i am not sure about your problem its not easy to understand
check your sheet for code and result


you should add expected result in your question too.

```js
function updateInvoice() {
  const blankArr = [];



  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const invoice = SS.getSheetByName("Invoice-2");
  const data = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(3, 2, SS.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getLastRow() - 3, 6).getValues();

  // const data = [
  //   ['client', 'Date', 'Service', 'Rate', 'Quantity', 'Unit cost'],
  //   ['abc', '2/23/2022', 'Service 1', '23', '2', '10.00'],
  // ]

  const clientName = invoice.getRange('B5').getValue();
  const startDate = new Date(invoice.getRange('C5').getValue());
  const endDate = new Date(invoice.getRange('D5').getValue());

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const r = data[i];
    if (r[0] === clientName && r[1] >= startDate && r[1] <= endDate) {
      blankArr.push(r);
    }
  }



  // if you want to use as function remve below line if you want to update onEdit then keep
  invoice.getRange(9, 2, blankArr.length, blankArr[0].length).setValues(blankArr);




  return blankArr;

}
```

Comment: Yes it solved my problem. God bless you "Dibash Sapkota" Five Stars *****